# Total unique number in array

Tags: c

I've got a weekly competitive programming assignment and I'm stuck with this particular question. It asks for the total unique number within an array as output. The constraints is as follow:

**1 <= N, M <= 10^6**

**N** for the total numbers to be scanned (length of array) and **M** for the integers of **N**.

Example of input and output:

```
Input:
7
1 2 2 3 4 5 5
Output:
5
```

My code goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    long int x;
    scanf("%ld", &x); getchar();
    long int arr[x];
        
    for(int j = 0; j<x; j++){
        scanf("%ld", &arr[j]); getchar();
    }
        
    long int counter = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j<x; j++){
        int flag = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k<j; k++){
            if(arr[j] == arr[k]){
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag != 1) counter++; 
    }
        
    printf("%ld\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

It gets the correct output but I got time limit verdict on my uni's online judge. Is there a way to optimize my code using C?? Map/dictionary algorithm may not work since this also has memory limit.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be `3`, not `5`?

Comment: Without knowing what the memory limits might be, it's hard to say. You might try to *sort* the array beforehand and then iterate through the array and increment a counter whenever you encounter a new value. The run-time is then O(NlogN)

Comment: Or 8 ( 1 + 3 + 4)?

Comment: Why do you need `long`? Is the `int` 16-bits? The two nested loops is a killer: a simple status array would need two linear passes, one of the input, one of the status array.

Comment: The answer is `5` because the unique numbers are `1,  2,  3,  4,  5` and the rest are duplicates. Therefore, there's `5 unique numbers` in that array.

Comment: That's not what "unique" means in my world.

Comment: You can solve this in linear time with 122 kB of memory.  It's considerably less memory than if you tried to store the actual array of numbers.

Comment: for the linear time complexity , you can use hash map to store the values, the size of the hash map will provide the number of unique values . here the space complexity is also linear.

Comment: "this also has memory limit" - **what** is the memory limit?

Comment: C, or C++. Pick one. The solutions would vary wildly depending on your pick.

Comment: Hint (in case it wasn't obvious from my previous comment): You only need 1 bit of information to record whether a value is seen or not, and you can solve the problem by examining one input at a time without storing them for later.  Look at your possible input range, and think how you would apply this.

Comment: The memory limit and time limit details aren't disclosed, apparently. Only question, constraints, and input output examples are provided.

I've read all the comments (thank you!). Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I'll try to solve it using the tips from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Sort the input element array and walk through it linearly. Duplicates will occur after one another. Singlets occur when values change from element to element.
2. Keep a 1M-element boolean array initialized to zero (i.e., "false"). Most boolean array implementations in standard libraries will take one byte per boolean. However, this space requirement can be reduced to ~1MB/8 (~125kB) by using a bit as a true/false flag, instead of a byte. Walk through the input element array linearly and use bit operations to set the `n`'th bit to one or "true". Keep a separate counter to mark singlets or unique values. If the bit for that value has already been set, move on to the next value.

For small input element arrays, the first solution uses more time (O(n log n) for common quicksort) but less space.

The second solution uses more space but less time (O(n) for a linear walk through the values).

Which you pick may depend on the parameters of your exercise.

---

To demonstrate the second approach, here is some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NVALUES 7
#define NBINS 1000000

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
  unsigned int values[NVALUES] = { 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 3 };
  unsigned char *bytes = NULL;
  size_t nbytes = (size_t) ceil((double) NBINS / (double) CHAR_BIT);
  unsigned int unique = 0;

  //
  // initialize the pointer of bytes
  //
  bytes = malloc(nbytes);
  if (!bytes) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  memset(bytes, 0, nbytes);

  //
  // walk through array of values
  //
  for (int idx = 0; idx < NVALUES; ++idx) {
    size_t offset = (size_t) floor((double) values[idx] / (double) CHAR_BIT);
    unsigned int nth = values[idx] % CHAR_BIT - 1;
    unsigned char byte = bytes[offset];
    /*
      if the n'th bit in byte is not set, increment the unique
      counter and set the n'th bit in that byte
    */
    if (!(byte & (1 << nth))) {
      unique++;
      byte |= (unsigned char) (1 << nth);
    }
  }

  //
  // print out the number of unique values
  //
  fprintf(stdout, "unique: %u\n", unique);

  //
  // cleanup
  //
  free(bytes);
  bytes = NULL;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`CHAR_BIT` is a constant that defines eight bits per byte (`unsigned char`). Some older systems may use a different value, but this would be very uncommon for modern systems.

The idea is to allocate memory for pointer to a set of bytes. For each integer value, calculate which of these bytes to test (i.e., `offset`) and either set the `nth` bit within that byte and increment the number of unique integers, or move on to the next value. At the end, report the number of unique integers.

Comment: 2) doesn't need an input array. Perhaps a popcount can be used to sum the status array bits.

Comment: That's true, you could just do bit operations (or integer equivalent) as you go along, I suppose. Depends how you want to read in and process input. I don't really know what the parameters of the exercise are.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer! I had tried approach 1) using bubble sort but still received 'TIME LIMIT' verdict. I would like to try approach 2) but I don't quite understand your explanation (I'm fairly new in coding). So, what I ought to do is: declare an array sized [**M**] for counting the occurrences of integers and separate counter for singlets. But, if I may ask, since the maximum possible number that could show up is 10^6, do I need to allocate [10^6] bytes for array memory? If 10^6 indeed shows up, I'll increment array index [10^6] and the singlets counter by one.

Comment: You need 10^6 bits, so you would allocate just enough bytes to cover that many bits. See the edited answer with one approach.

Comment: For the first approach, you would probably not want to use a bubblesort as it has quadratic runtime, O(n^2). That's probably why you are running into a time limit. A better sort would be to use the builtin qsort function, which runs in O(n log n) time. Search online for examples of running qsort; there are many.

Comment: Oooh! Kind of hard to implement your code since I haven't learnt about malloc and the bit/bytes stuff, but I do get the gist of what you're trying to convey now. I was able to make a rookie imitation of your code and got Accepted verdict. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Sorting O(n log n) then searching O(n) , will bring the complexity down to O(n log n) if you don't want to use extra space. However with constant extra space you can solve in O(n) time.